# JProfiler 11.0.2 Mac M1 support?

Tags: jprofiler

Issue when running a jar with the agent flag:

`java -agentpath:/Applications/JProfiler.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/macos/libjprofilerti.jnilib=port=8849  -jar name-of-jar`

issue:

'/Applications/JProfiler.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/macos/libjprofilerti.jnilib' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have (i386,x86_64), need (arm64e)))

I presume this is due to the Mac M1, is there a version of JProfiler which supports the M1?

Answer (score 0):

JProfiler 11.0.2 does not support M1 processors, support has been added since JProfiler 12.0.

```
Support for profiling on macOS ARM has been added. While profiling JVMs compiled for the x86 architecture is possible on new ARM-based macOS machines via Rosetta, new JVMs compiled directly for the new ARM architecture require a different native profiling agent.
Starting with this release, the macOS profiling agent is a universal binary that contains implementations for both x64 and ARM64.
At the time of the 12.0 release, JProfiler is not bundled with an ARM JRE yet, so the JProfiler GUI will run via Rosetta on macOS ARM machines. A release that includes an ARM JRE is expected shortly as corresponding JREs become available.
```

Reference: https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/whatsnew12.html